# Best approach to proxy requests in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'd like to provide a proxy in node.js. Only one request should consume the original data-source and send data to list of connected clients. What is better approach?

1/ keep clients in a list and send every data-chunk to each of them, eg.:

```
// on client connection ('res' is client's response stream):
self.clients.push(res);

// ... then, on data event:
for (var i = self.clients.length; i--;) {
    self.clients[i].write(someDataChunk);
}
```

2/ or, create one duplex (let's say PassThrough) stream, write data-chunks into it, and simply pipe output to every client's request?

```
var out = new PassThrough();
out.write(someDataChunk);
out.pipe(res); // again, 'res' is client's response stream
```

3/ or any other, better approach?

Comment: Did you look at: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/tree/master/lib/http-proxy/passes?

Comment: I will look at it, thanks. One important note - the original data source is a "dirty" stream which needs some transformations. That's the reason why I cannot just pass data to clients.